# Memory leak when using CallSite

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, memory-leaks

Let's say i have an html helper that at some point calls

```
 GetDynamicValueOrNull(html.ViewBag, "SomePropName")
```

which is

```
private static object GetDynamicValueOrNull(dynamic dyn, string memberName)
{
    var dynamicObj = dyn as DynamicObject;

    if (dynamicObj == null) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    return dynamicObj.GetDynamicMemberNames().Contains(memberName)
        ? ExtractDynamicMember(dynamicObj, memberName)
        : null;
}

private static object ExtractDynamicMember(object obj, string memberName)
{
    var binder = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, memberName, obj.GetType(),
         new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });
    var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(binder);
    return callsite.Target(callsite, obj);
}
```

The problem is that at some point this code is turning into one big memory leak with a stack trace:

```
Stack trace:    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Resize(Int32 newSize, Boolean forceNewHashCodes)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.SYMTBL.InsertChildNoGrow(Symbol child)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.SymFactoryBase.newBasicSym(SYMKIND kind, Name name, ParentSymbol parent)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.SymFactory.CreateLocalVar(Name name, ParentSymbol parent, CType type)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.PopulateLocalScope(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, Scope pScope, ArgumentObject[] arguments, IEnumerable`1 parameterExpressions, Dictionary`2 dictionary)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.BindCore(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder action, RuntimeBinder binder, IEnumerable`1 args, IEnumerable`1 arginfos, DynamicMetaObject onBindingError)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpGetMemberBinder.FallbackGetMember(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicObject.MetaDynamic.CallMethodWithResult(String methodName, DynamicMetaObjectBinder binder, Expression[] args, Fallback fallback, Fallback fallbackInvoke)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicObject.MetaDynamic.CallMethodWithResult(String methodName, DynamicMetaObjectBinder binder, Expression[] args, Fallback fallback)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicObject.MetaDynamic.BindGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, LabelTarget returnLabel)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MyHelperName.ExtractDynamicMember(Object obj, String memberName)
   ...
```

I've heard that this could be because of DLR caching policy, is this correct and is there any workaround/fix available for this case?

Comment: looks like a classic case of doing something in too a complicated  way

Comment: Should i just pass ViewData and target my objects by key in dictionary manner?

Comment: That looks like it might be the issue https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/15397 hopes to fix.